# Python - Check if all n numbers are present in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if my list contains all the numbers from 0 to the maximum number of the list

For ex this list contains all the numbers from 0 to 7:

```
l = [0,2,1,7,6,5,4,3]
```

but this list doesn't as it doesnt have 4 -

```
l = [0,2,1,6,5,7,3]
```

I try using zip:

```
all(x==y+1 for x, y in zip(sorted(l[1:]), sorted(l)))
```

but this doesnt work..

FOR EXAMPLE -

```
l = [0,3,2,5]
```

doesnt have 1 and 4 so it should return false!

where as -

```
l = [0,2,3,1,4,5]
```

has all the numbers from 0 to 5 so it should return true!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use `zip` with multiple `zip` function.You can use `sorted` :

```
if sorted(l)==list(range(max(l)+1))
```

example :

```
>>> sorted(l)==list(range(max(l)+1))
False
>>> l= [0,2,1,7,6,5,4,3] 
>>> sorted(l)==list(range(max(l)+1))
True
```

Comment: This doesnt work ... i want to check if ALL the numbers are present from 0 to n, with n being the max number in the list. For ex - if max number in the list is 5 then 0,1,2,3,4,5 should be present irrespective of order.

Comment: @FallenAngel Why? you said *all the numbers from 0 to the maximum number of the list* and this is what you want .

Comment: Although not mentioned in the original question - I am afraid this solution won't work - if the original list has duplicates and has more elements than the compare list. eg. `l = [0,1,2,4,5,6,8,2,7,2,4,5]` (does not contain 3 and 2, 4, 5 are duplicates). But agreed, it's not mentioned in the original question whether two lists are of same size.

Comment: @gabhijit This is another scenario, and can be solve by a `set`

Answer (score 1):

Slow and dirty solition:

```
def f(myList):
    ll = [i for i in range(max(myList))] 
    diff = set(ll).difference(set(myList))
    if diff: return (False, diff)
    return (True, "sequence without blanks")

#lets test:
t1,t2 = [0,1,7,4,5,2],[3,5,4,2,1,0]
print(map(f,(t1,t2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As always - sets are my favorite here -

Original list

```
l = [ 1, 2,4 3, 0, 5,6,7]
```

another compare list

```
l2 = range(8)

# intersection of two sets is the set of compare list. 
# This solution would work when the size of original list is different than size of the compare list
set(l) & set(l2) == set(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try test set:

```
len(set(l))==max(l)+1
```